# Type casting gives different results for different compilers

Tags: c, casting

This is just a basic stuff ,but still confused with this

My code consists of a line

```
signed char var = 0x80;
unsigned short temp_val;
temp_val = (unsigned short)var ;
```

When I compiled this code using **XC32** compiler and executed the program the result obtained was **0xFF80** as expected.

But when compiled using **CCS Compiler** for *MSP430* the result obtained was **0x0080**

Why this difference with respect to compilers?

Can somebody please explain this from a Processor's view of type casting?

Comment: What are the values of `CHAR_BIT` on *both* implementations ?

Comment: Both uses 8 bits for a char data type

Comment: Removed tags: All C code is compiled, and cross-compiling refers either to translating object code from one target to another, or compiling for a normally self-hosting platform on another host.

Answer (score 1):

This is signed integer overflow because `0x80` equals 128 and, if `CHAR_BIT` is 8 as you say, then `signed char` only goes up to 127.

```
signed char var = 0x80;
```

Signed integer overflow produces undefined behavior.

Try with `signed char var = -128` instead.

If that produces the same result, it's a compiler bug. Converting a negative number to an `unsigned` type subtracts it from the corresponding modulus, which is one greater than the maximum value of that type.

Answer (score 0):

That will happen if `char` has more than 8 bits, which it is certainly allowed to. (It can't have fewer.) It would also happen if `short` turned out to be only 8 bits, which wouldn't conform to standard C, but the CCS compiler only claims to be "97%" compliant.

The size of the various integer datatypes is conditioned by the processor, but ultimately it is defined by the compiler, which might even have options to change the sizes.

I don't know anything about the MSP430, but Google told me it is a 16-bit chip. It is possible that its memory is not byte-addressable, in which case a `char` would have to occupy the full 16 bits. (**Edit**: apparently, it is byte-addressable, so scratch that theory.)

Comment: The memory of the MSP430 family of uC's is byte addressable.

Comment: @user3477950: OK, scratch that theory.

Comment: Nevertheless, it was a valid statement, just saying.

Comment: @rici until a clear answer to my comment squelches it, your theory about `char` size still has merit. Don't scratch it just yet.

Comment: @WhozCraig: `sizeof(unsigned short)` would also be useful. I'm going to bed, though.

Comment: sizeof(unsigned short) is 16 bits

Answer (score 0):

Any char can be, **to the compiler**, various lengths depending on the **compiler** settings, including 7 bits (rare these days), 8 bits (what most people think it is), 16 bits (getting more common especially with Unicode), I have even come across machine/compiler combinations that would **store** each char in a 64 bit locations.

This sort of discrepancy between compilers are why MISRA C has rules against:

- Base Types
- Bit operations on signed types

Just because the chip is byte addressable it doesn't mean any given compiler uses it that way ***by default*** since byte operations on 16 and bigger storage systems can incur a processing overhead some compilers default to memory size operations to optimise speed rather than storage.

I would suggest searching the compilers documentation for **pack**.

A few years ago the default Solaris compiler used a 64 bit location for each field in a bit field - *luckily for us Solaris gcc didn't so we were able to complete the project.*

It would also be interesting to try:

```
signed char var = 0x80;
signed short temp_val1;
unsigned short temp_val2;

temp_val1 = (signed short)var ;
temp_val2 = (unsigned short)temp_val1;
```

This might highlight problems with sign extending in that compiler.

Comment: a `char` **cannot** be a 7-bit type, because the C standard required that `CHAR_BIT >= 8`. And `char` doesn't have 16 bits in any desktop platforms because POSIX requires that `CHAR_BIT == 8`. Only ancient and DSP platforms have a non-8-bit char

Comment: @phuclv: Exactly C was created in the early 1970s but the first ANSI standard wasn't ratified until 1989 - even then there were a lot of non-ANSI implementations _(there still are including by default most versions of MS C)_ and as well as the embedded world (which MISRA was specifically aimed at) there workstations & super computers many of which use a memory location bigger than 8 bits to store a char. On windows machines there is char and  WCHAR to add to the confusion and of course Unicode string elements can, depending on encoding, be various multiples of 8. Teletype systems used 5 bits.